# How to decrease the number of `addEventListener` using Event Delegation. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have just one `addEventListener`using Event Delegation

```js
// Get  button

var btnAll = document.getElementById('btnAll');
var btnUrfa = document.getElementById('btnUrfa');
var btnRookies = document.getElementById('btnRookies');


// Listen for button click
btnAll.addEventListener('click', fetchAll);
btnUrfa.addEventListener('click', fetchUrfa);
btnRookies.addEventListener('click', fetchRookies);


function fetchAll() {
    $.getJSON('/fetchDataAll', function (data) {
        $("#show").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

    $.getJSON('/fetchDataAll01', function (data) {
        $("#show01").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show01").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

    $.getJSON('/fetchDataAll1', function (data) {
        $("#show1").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show1").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });


    $.getJSON('/fetchDataAll11', function (data) {
        $("#show11").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show11").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

}

function fetchRookies() {
    $.getJSON('/fetchDataRookies', function (data) {
        $("#show").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

    $.getJSON('/fetchDataRookies01', function (data) {
        $("#show01").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show01").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

    $.getJSON('/fetchDataRookies1', function (data) {
        $("#show1").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show1").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });


    $.getJSON('/fetchDataRookies11', function (data) {
        $("#show11").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show11").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

}
function fetchUrfa() {
    $.getJSON('/fetchDataUrfa', function (data) {
        $("#show").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

    $.getJSON('/fetchDataUrfa01', function (data) {
        $("#show01").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show01").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });

    $.getJSON('/fetchDataUrfa1', function (data) {
        $("#show1").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show1").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });


    $.getJSON('/fetchDataUrfa11', function (data) {
        $("#show11").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#show11").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
                "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
                "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

        });
    });
}

////// gettting data on first load

$.getJSON('/fetchDataAll', function (data) {
    $("#show").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function () {
        $("#show").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
            "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
            "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

    });
});

$.getJSON('/fetchDataAll01', function (data) {
    $("#show01").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function () {
        $("#show01").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
            "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
            "<h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

    });
});

$.getJSON('/fetchDataAll1', function (data) {
    $("#show1").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function () {
        $("#show1").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
            "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
            "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

    });
});


$.getJSON('/fetchDataAll11', function (data) {
    $("#show11").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function () {
        $("#show11").append("<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['playerName'] + "</p>",
            "<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>" + this['teamName'] + "</p>",
            "<h3 style='color:#D0021B'>" + this['scoreChange'] + " %</h3>");

    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but since you're already using jQuery, you may as well use jQuery's built-in support for it rather than doing the work yourself: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Comment: give the buttons a common class name and fetch elements by document.querySelector('.common-class') then bind the event. Inside the event different the elements by using some attribute value or id using event.target

Comment: And put the fetchDataALL calls in a function, avoid duplication of code.

Comment: All the methods above do the same as just binding an event handler to each of all matched elements implicitly. That means, there are still _n_ event handlers registered. In fact, an event handler is not much more than just an array of functions to be called when an event on a specific element is fired.

What you can do, however, is to attach the event handler to a parent element (maybe even the body element) and evaluate the `event.target`. If it is placed within an element with a certain class (see `$.closest`), run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when dealing with dynamic content, binding event handlers directly to the newly inserted elements gets very resource hungry, it affects your runtime behavior negatively.

What you can do, is bind an event handler to a common ancestor element (such as a wrapping `div` or even the document.body. All you need to do, is giving each element that has to be activated on your event a separate class name to identify them properly.

Example:

```
<body>
    <div class="clickactive">
        <img src="...">    
    </div>
    <!-- ... some more dynamic "clickactive" elements -->
</body>
```

In your js, you just do something like this:

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).closest(".clickactive").length > 0){
       // handle your click on $(e.target).closest[0]
    }
}
```

That way, you

- don't need to worry about applying your event handler over and over again for every newly inserted element
- you only have **one** event handler activated

The downside, however (especially when binding to the body): Your click gets called every time *any* element is clicked within the element you bound the event handler to (of course, the condition is false and that code is not executed, but the condition is evaluated anyway). So best practice is to bind to the closest common ancestor.