# Is there way to decrease the number of `addEventListener` using Event Delegation. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Is it possible to have just one `addEventListener` using Event Delegation. Anyone to help?**

```js
// Get  button

const btnAll = document.querySelector('#btnAll')
const btnUrfa = document.querySelector('#btnUrfa')
const btnRookies = document.querySelector('#btnRookies')

const show = document.querySelector('#show')
const show01 = document.querySelector('#show01')
const show1 = document.querySelector('#show1')
const show11 = document.querySelector('#show11')

// Listen for button click
btnAll.addEventListener('click', fetchAll)
btnUrfa.addEventListener('click', fetchUrfa)
btnRookies.addEventListener('click', fetchRookies)

function fetchAll() {

    fetch('/fetchDataAll')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                <h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+ ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataAll01')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show01.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show01").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+ ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataAll1')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show1.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show1").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#D0021B'> ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataAll11')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show11.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show11").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#D0021B'> ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function fetchRookies() {

    fetch('/fetchDataRookies')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                <h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+ ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataRookies01')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show01.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show01").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+ ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });


    fetch('/fetchDataRookies1')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show1.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show1").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#D0021B'> ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataRookies11')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show11.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show11").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#D0021B'> ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function fetchUrfa() {

    fetch('/fetchDataUrfa')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                <h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+ ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataUrfa01')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show01.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show01").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#66FF13'>+ ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });


    fetch('/fetchDataUrfa1')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show1.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show1").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#D0021B'> ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    fetch('/fetchDataUrfa11')
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
        .then(function (data) {
            show11.innerHTML = ''
            let players = data.result; // Get the results
            return players.forEach(function (player) {
                $("#show11").append(`<p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.playerName}</p>
                    <p style='color:#FFFFFF'>${player.teamName}</p>
                    <h3 style='color:#D0021B'> ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`)
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: You want to remove event listeners? Well there's the [**`.removeEventListener()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) method...

Comment: Yes I did changed it from jQuery to JavaScipt. Now I need to implement event delegation

Comment: Duplicate of [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760448/), asked by another user.

Comment: No, I do not want to remove event listeners. I want to implement event delegation . Meaning that instead of uding multiple one I will have only one that will be able to listen to all the events in this context

Comment: This is not a dublicate question. I refactored the code from jQuery to es6. It took me some time since I am new to this

Comment: ^ If you modified your code, why did you not [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49760448/edit) your original question, rather than go to all the hassle of making a second account just to write a duplicate question?

Comment: Because I need to wait 5 days, too long. No one would answer an edited question . I need to post a new one

Comment: @JohnJohn And apparently made a new account to do it. The answer here is: Yes it's possible. What have you tried? How about showing us what you've tried in using event delegation. What research have you done and how has that not worked for you?

Comment: You have a huge amount of duplicate code in your `fetch` functions. IMO it would be much more helpful cleaning that up than converting 3 lines to one. Note if you want to combine them use a common class in your HTML and select that.

Comment: I know how to do event delegation but I have three different functions to (fetchAll, fetchUrfa, fetchRookies)  I am not sure how to implement it without having one listener for each function

Comment: @JohnJohn "I know how to do event delegation but I have three different functions to (fetchAll, fetchUrfa, fetchRookies) I am not sure how to implement it without having one listener for each function". Meaning you don't know anything about event delegation. How about you put "javascript event delegation" in a search engine and then READ and COMPREHEND the first article you find. It's not our fault that you can't wait because you already waited until last minute on your project you have due for class.

Comment: I have no project to submit . I am trying to learn JavaScript on my own. I did implemented event delegation and it works well . I am challenging my self and trying to implement event delegation in a different situation that I am not sure how to resolve. If anyone can show me an example how to implement an event delegation having more then two function I would appreciate it .

Comment: Hey guys. This is not a duplicate question and certainly not worthy of the downvotes it got.

Comment: @JohnJohn don't forget to [**merge**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) the account later. Too many Johns here already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a common class to your buttons, for example `"fetcher-btn"`. Then add a data attribute (for example `"data-fetcher"`) to each button specifying which type of "fetching" they're going to perform (`"all"`, `"ufra"` or `"rookies"`). Then group the functions that perform the fetching in an object where the keys are the data attributes and the value is the functions. Finally, add a click event listener to one of the buttons common ancestors (preferably a closer one), where you check if the clicked element has a class `"fetcher-btn"` (meaning it's one of our buttons) and if the function specified in its data attribute exists, if so call that function:

**Example:**

```js
var fetcherObject = {                                          // the object that maps the data-fetcher attributes to their equivalent functions
  "all": fetchAll,
  "ufra": fetchUfra,
  "rookies": fetchRookies
};

document.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {              // add the click event listener to a common ancestor of the buttons (here document)
  var target = ev.target;                                      // get the target of the click event
  if(target.classList.contains("fetcher-btn")) {               // if the target is one of out buttons (has the class fetcher-btn)
    var fetchFn = fetcherObject[target.dataset.fetcher];       // use its data-fetcher (dataset.fetcher) value to get the function from fetcherObject
    if(fetchFn) {                                              // if that function exists (to make the test even strictier add typeof fetchFn === "function" and fetcherObject.hasOwnProperty(target.dataset.fetcher) checks)
      fetchFn();                                               // call the fetching function
    }
  }
});

function fetchAll() {
  console.log("fetchAll is called!");
}

function fetchUfra() {
  console.log("fetchUfra is called!");
}

function fetchRookies() {
  console.log("fetchRookies is called!");
}
```

```html
<button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="all">Fetch all</button>
<button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="ufra">Fetch ufra</button>
<button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="rookies">Fetch rookies</button>
```

**Note:** Your fetching functions could be refactored and reduced quite a bit (as they seem to be performing similar tasks), I'd suggest you go ahead and do that on [CodeReviewSE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (as SO is not for that kind of thing).

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim !!! I see what you did. Need to set a custom attribute and get it by using dataset. Plus Object! I will try to use CodeReviewSE.